# How to substitute differential equation into another?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to make a repeated differentiation of the differential equation and replacing the result with the previous answer.   But I do not know how to substitute answer into another.  I tried Merge, Join, Union, Replace and it does not work.  Below is the example code,

```
 ClearAll;
 x[0]=1;
 x'[0]=2;
 equation = x''[t]==x'[t]-x[t];
 answer = D[equation,t]
 newanswer = Join[answer, equation]
```

The answer is  $x'''[t]==x''[t]-x'[t]$.  I want to substitute equation in the answer or replace $x''[t]$ in the answer with $x'[t]-x[t] $ as defined in the equation so that I should get a newanswer $ x'''[t]==x'[t]-x[t]-x'[t]$.  Furthermore, I should later on substitute with $ x[0]=1$ and $x'[0]=2$.  What are the functions that will allow me to do operations like that? Am I defining equation and differentiating it incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
newanswer = Eliminate[{answer, equation}, x''[t]]

(*  -x'''[t]] == x[t]  *)
```

Or this:

```
newanswer = Reduce[{answer, equation}, x'''[t], {x''[t]}]

(*  x'''[t]] == -x[t]  *)
```

As for what to do "later on," perhaps this:

```
Reduce[{answer, equation, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 2} /. t -> 0]

(*  x'''[0] == -1 && x''[0] == 1 && x'[0] == 2 && x[0] == 1  *)
```

Or this:

```
Solve[{answer, equation, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 2} /. t -> 0]

(*  {{x[0] -> 1, x'[0] -> 2, x''[0] -> 1, x'''[0] -> -1}}  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could define:

```
x[0] = 1;
x'[0] = 2;
Derivative[n_?(GreaterEqualThan[2])][x] = Derivative[n-1][x][#] - Derivative[n-2][x][#]&;
```

Then:

```
x'''[t]
x'''[0]
x''''''[0]
```

> -x[t]

> -1

> 1